# calling a php file from jsp on clicking one button

Tags: php, jsp

i want to know how to call php file from on clicking some button in jsp file. can u please let me  know a ways to do that.

Comment: JSP produces HTML. HTML has a `<a>` element to link to some other URL and `<form>` element to submit to some other URL. PHP listens on HTTP requests and produces HTML as well. Simple as that. You seem to think that JSP and PHP runs in the webbrowser, but this is untrue. They runs in the webserver and it's HTML which runs in the webbrowser.

Answer (score 1):

If your environment allows it, this is done via a simple `<a href="/phplocation/phpPage.php">click</a>`

And in order for the environment to support this, you'd have to use Apache server and connect it with tomcat. But that's another question, for server fault